# get "from" attribute value from the asp.net smtp client configuration in the web.config

Tags: asp.net, xml, smtp

How to get the "from" attribute value from the asp.net SMTP client configuration in the web.config file?

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="administrator@somewebsite.com">
    <network host="somehosting" userName="someusername" password="somepassword"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var mailSettings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings");
string from = mailSettings.From;
```

Comment: The idea is right, but that code doesn't work. The correct code is:                 foreach (ConfigurationSectionGroup csg  in WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config").SectionGroups)                
                    if (csg.Name== "system.net")               
                        foreach (ConfigurationSectionGroup csg2 in csg.SectionGroups)                      if (csg2.Name == "mailSettings")
                            {
                                var mailSettings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)csg2;return mailSettings.Smtp.From;                            }

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use named sections:

Application config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="mailSettings">
    <section name="DefaultSmtpProvider" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection"/>
   </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

 <mailSettings>
  <DefaultSmtpProvider from="YourAddress@YourDomain.com">
   <network host="@host" userName="@userName" password="@password" defaultCredentials ="false" />
  </DefaultSmtpProvider>
 </mailSettings>
</configuration>
```

Init Code:

```cs
SmtpSection smtpSettings = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("mailSettings/DefaultSmtpProvider");
var message= new MailMessage(smtpSettings.From, recipientAddress};
```

This will also allow you to have multiple smtp settings within one config in case you ever need to switch smtpClients. I forgot to state, you will have to build up the smtp client manually if this approach is used:

```cs
new SmtpClient
        {
            DeliveryMethod = smtpSettings.DeliveryMethod,
            Host = smtpSettings.Network.Host,
            UseDefaultCredentials = smtpSettings.Network.DefaultCredentials,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpSettings.Network.UserName, smtpSettings.Network.Password)
        };
```